# Copy Pandas DataFrame into multiple files by Value Range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a DataFrame, lets say 3000x3000 with int values from 0 to 10 and I want to break it down into categories and save into separate files.

Categories should be something like 0-3, 4-5, 5-10 for example.

As a result I want to get 3 files of the same shape but only with relevant values per category and these values should stay at the original positions.

At first I thought to copy df for each category and use replace to remove all irrelevant values, but it doesn't sound right.

Hope this is not very confusing.

df example:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   7   0
2   0   0   2   3   0   0   0   0   6   7
3   0   0   2   3   0   0   0   0   9   6
4   0   0   0   1   0   0   5   4   8   7
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   5   4   0   0
6   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   5   0   0
7   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   4   0   0
8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   0   0
9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

as the result I want 3 dataframes:

cat1:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   2   3   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   2   3   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

cat2:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0   0   5   4   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   5   4   0   0
6   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   5   0   0
7   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   4   0   0
8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   0   0
9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

cat3:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   7   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   6   7
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   9   6
4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   8   7
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: can you show an example_df along with the expected output

Comment: @Kenan, updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `where`

```
df1 = df.where((df > 0) & (df <=3), 0)
   
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  2  3  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  2  3  0  0  0  0  0  0
4  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
7  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
9  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

You can write similar logic for df2 and df3

Comment: Thank you! Will try in the morning!